# Создание объекта с неопределенным количеством подобъектов

Tags: javascript, jquery, объекты

Есть HTML элементы с атрибутам name="1/settings/width", name="1/settings/name" и т.д. Нужно разбить значение по "/" и занести в объект settings = { 1: { settings: { width: value, name: value } } }.
Как можно это сделать лучше если дальше может появится больше количество подобъектов

```
$('[name]').each(function() {
  var split = $(this).prop('name').split('/');
  if (typeof obj_setting[split[0]] != 'object') {
    obj_setting[split[0]] = {}
  }

  if (typeof obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]] != 'object') {
    obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]] = {}
  }

  if (split.length == 2) {
    obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]] = $(this).val();
    return
  }

  if (split.length == 3) {
    if (obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]][split[2]] != 'object') {
      obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]][split[2]] = {};
      obj_setting[split[0]][split[1]][split[2]] = $(this).val();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разделите `name` по разделителю, и в цикле обойдите этот массив, передвигаясь по объекту с использованием полученных ключей. На последней итерации вписывайте значение.

```js
var result = {};

$("input[name]").each(function(){
   let path = $(this).attr('name').split('/');
   let val = $(this).val();   
   let vkey = path.pop();   
   
   var tmp = path.reduce(function(acc, v){
                      return (v in acc) ? acc[v] :  acc[v] = {};                
                  }, result);
   
   tmp[vkey] = val; 
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="1/settings/width" value="w1"/>
<input name="1/settings/name" value="name1"/>
<input name="2/settings/width" value="w2"/>
<input name="2/settings/qwe/asd" value="zxc"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помог.

Comment: @Nikolay10987 немного изменил код